# file upload from pc to device or sdcard android

Tags: android

I want to upload file from pc to device or sdcard but i dont know how it is posible.

Could you help?

Comment: What type of connection do you have? Your Android phone model?

Comment: i am using web server. and use device ip address for it

Comment: I would like to know how as well.